# ActiveRecord merge is behaving strangely with rolify with_role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rolify

Given example models like these:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
  belongs_to :baz
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  belongs_to :qux
end

class Qux < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  has_many :bazzes
end
```

The following code works as expected:

```
records = Foo.joins(bar: { baz: :qux }).merge(Qux.where(x: 17))
```

However

```
records = Foo.joins(bar: { baz: :qux }).merge(Qux.with_role(:admin))
```

returns a collect of `Foo` records that have been populated with values from the `quxxes` table.  This means that for example `records.z` where `z` is a column on `foos` but not on `quxxes` will give a missing attribute error.  You can almost fix this with:

```
records = Foo.select('foos.*').joins(bar: { baz: :qux }).merge(Qux.with_role(:admin))
```

But this is deceptive as it will take values from columns not on `quxxes` from `foos` but the columns that have the same names, for example `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` in a typical rails app will come from `quxxes`.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, where are your `has_many` or `has_one` associations?

Comment: @User089247 I'm trying query for all of the foo records that belong to a bar that belong to a baz that belong to a qux that is associated with an admin role using rolify.

Comment: @nikkon226 nothing in active record requires that relations be specified in both directions.  If it helps your intuition I can add some has_many relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turns out to be that rolify adds a select to the `with_role` relation (on line 23 of [this adapter](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/blob/master/lib/rolify/adapters/active_record/resource_adapter.rb)).

After looking into how `ActiveRecord` stores select statements (see lines 249 and 69 of [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb)), we came up with the following solution:

```
records = Foo.joins(bar: { baz: :qux }).merge(Qux.with_role(:admin)).tap { |rel| rel.select_values = ['foos.*'] }
```

This removes the select added by the merge and replaces it with our own.  Alternately we can also just move the select to the end of the call chain which seems to work too:

```
records = Foo.joins(bar: { baz: :qux }).merge(Qux.with_role(:admin)).select('foos.*')
```